# HuggingFacePipeline With AutomodelForCausalLLM 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: pipeline, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, large-language-model, llama

If i use the following code, i get an error message:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'.

Normally im running it with llm chain, but i think something is wrong with my model.
The last models I used I was able to run with Llamacpp. That was easier for me.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help.

```
model_path = "../models/openbuddy-llama2-34b-v11.1-bf16"  
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)

nf4_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4',
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
    max_memory=24000  
)

pipeline = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_path,
        quantization_config=nf4_config,
        )


  
llm2 = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipeline)

print(llm2("Hi, How are you"))
```